# Asp.net MVC4 partial view loading inside popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am having an issue with a MVC4 app I have a view that has two partial view on it.
My main view is opening inside the popup. My screen open successfully with  2 partial view on a popup window.

Upper part of my view contains data entry/edit( partial view) and bottom part is display ( partial view).

Display part partial view contains web grid and eac a hyperlink ( edit and delete ) . when user click on edit , application should load the entry/edit view inside the same page.

My application should load entry/edit partial view on the same window .

Please suggest how to achieve this.
see the below code i am using on display view.

----------------------------------------------------------  First Partial view---

```
@model IEnumerable<Peabody.LMS.WebApp.ViewModels.AUTenement.TenementTypeLookupViewModel>
<div id="gridContent">
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort: "TypeCode", rowsPerPage: 10, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
}

@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table",mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    firstText: "<< First",
    previousText: "< Previous", 
    nextText: "Next >",
    lastText: "Last >>",
    footerStyle: "foot-grid",
    columns:
    grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("TypeCode",header:"TenementType Code"),
        grid.Column("TypeDescription", header: "Tenement Description"),
        grid.Column("Country", header: "Country"),
        grid.Column("State", header: "State"),
        grid.Column("LastModifiedBy", header: "Last Modified By"),
        grid.Column("LastModifiedOn", header: "Modified On"),


        grid.Column("Actions", "",@<a href='/TenementTypeLookup/LoadHeaderEdit/@item.TypeCode' ><img src="~/Images/edit-icon.png" alt='Edit' /></a>, style: "width:auto"),
        grid.Column("", "",@<a href='/TenementTypeLookup/Delete/@item.TypeCode' ><img src="~/Images/Delete-icon.png" alt='Edit' /></a>, style: "width:auto")


   ))
    </div>

------------------------------
```

---

Answer (score 0):

the best way I have found is to load the partial with an ajax call.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnDisplay', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
        data: {
            Field1: 'field1',
            Field2: 'field2'
        }
        success: function (result) {
            $('.targetDiv').html(result);
        }
});
```

then on your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Action(string Field1, string Field2){
    var model = //populate model from database
    return PartialView("_PartialName", model);
}
```

so the ajax call will call the controller and pass whatever parameters you want.  Then you can build the model and return the partial view.  In the success of the ajax call it will take the returned partial view and put them into the whatever your target it (a div with class .targetDiv in this case)